# How to show that the map $E \times I \to E: (v,t) \to t\cdot v$ is continuous on a vector bundle $E$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a topological space $M$. I want to show that $\pi:E \to M$ is a homotopy equivalence.

To show this, I use the zero section $\zeta:M \to E$. Then $\pi \circ \zeta = Id_M$ and $\zeta \circ \pi$ is the zero map in the vector space $E_p$ for $p\in M$.

So the natural homotopy map is $H:E \times I \to E$ defined by $(v,t) \to t\cdot v$, where this operation makes sense if $v \in E_p$.

But I don't know how to confirm that this map will be continuous. It is continuous on each $E_x \times I \to E_x$ as it is just a scalar multiplication in the vector space, but how do I know that scalar multiplication is continuous on the entire total space of the bundle?

Comment: Do you deduce continuity on an open set of $E$ of the form $\pi^{-1}(U)$ if the bundle is trivial on $U$?

Comment: @TedShifrin No I don't know why multiplication would be continuous if the bundle is trivial.

Comment: Fix $c\in\Bbb R$. Then the map $(x,v)\mapsto (x,cv)$ is continuous on $U\times\Bbb R^k$. Then jazz it up to $(x,v,t)\mapsto (x,tv)$ with $U\times\Bbb R^k\times I\to U\times\Bbb R^k$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Precompose this with $\Phi \times Id_I : \pi^{-1}(U) \times I \to U\times R^k \times I$ and postcompose this with the local trivialization $\Phi^{-1}: U\times R^k \to \pi^{-1}(U)$ and $\Phi^{-1}(x,tv)$  is the map that multiplies $v\in E$ by $t$. Thank you.